# Setting mp3 bitrate with xuggler

Tags: java, audio, xuggle, xuggler

I need to convert audio files to `mp3` format with a 192 kbps bitrate using xuggler.

The method `addAudioStream`, which implements the `IWriter` interface, is writing the audio files at 64 kbps.

How can I set the bit rate?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the Stream Coder for the audio stream and call setBitrate like this:

```
getStreamCoder().setBitRate(192*1024);
```

Comment: No, it doesn't affect the output.

Comment: I have a similar problem: I use setBitRate method, but there is no effect on the output file. Have you resolved your problem? How?

Comment: Check [IStreamCoder.setBitRate(int)](http://build.xuggle.com/view/Stable/job/xuggler_jdk5_stable/javadoc/java/api/com/xuggle/xuggler/IStreamCoder.html#setBitRate%28int%29) documentation